# Can i use Google Drive to manage an account system?

Tags: security, google-apps-script, http-post, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to create an **account system**, that let's a user sign up, and later get access to specific contents, depending on kind of subscription (free/payed).

The system should work like this:

1) The user **signs up** in a webpage, using a form performing a **POST request** to a Google Script published as service, linked to a Google Spreadsheet.
2) Using the **doPost()** method, data from signup (mail, name, password...) **are collected** in a Google Spreadsheet.
3) From another webpage the user can **log-in**, using a form performing a **GET request** to the Google Script that checks for username and password, and, if matching, retrives different content depending on kind of subscription (free/payed).

The specific linked questions are:
A) **What are the security threats?** I mean, I'm not an expert, but to me seems there are no risk of spreading informations around the web (the spreadsheet will be shared only to me), and i cannot think of methods of injection or data sniffing...but as I told, I'm no expert.

B) **What are the ethical lacks?** Because since they will sign-up, I will see all their datas, and also username and password...

C) **Other problems I didn't see?** Even suggestions, or other methods to use, this one seems to me so easy and smooth (I can use without problems Google APIs, HTML and JS)...like, too good to be true!

Already thanks for the patience of reading this all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an account system with Google drive just like you stated ,i know it sounds too good to be true.The only way you can be hacked is if you have malwares in you computer that sniff passwords because its practically hard (impossible) to hack almighty Google.just make sure your work environment(computer) is safe of malware because that's the only way you can be compromised (also browser settings).OTHER THAN THAT YOU ARE GOOD TO GO.

Comment: ok, I'll keep it clean, promised! :) thanks for such fast support!